# How to Compare strings in java

Tags: java, string, compare

I have a program I'm making where when the user type in a mood, it will output a quote based on it. I need to tell the program
`if the user is happy, then output this text` The problem is, I don't know how to get the program to recognize the input and output the text based on it... here's what I have for code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class modd {
    public static void main(String arrgs[]) {
        System.out.println("Enter your mood:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String mood = sc.nextLine();

        if (sc = happy) {
            System.out.println("test");

            if (sc = sad) {
                System.out.println("I am sad");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd start by taking a look at the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) on `String`s

Comment: Learn how to compare strings. `switch` also might help.  Also your input is `mood` (not `sc`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it looks like you are dealing with the wrong variable `sc`. I think you meant to compare `mood`.

When dealing with strings, always use `.equals()`, not `==`. `==` compares the references, which is often unreliable, while `.equals()` compares the actual values.

It's also good practice to either convert your string to all uppercase or all lower case. I'll use lower case in this example with `.toLowerCase()`. `.equalsIgnoreCase()` is also another quick way around any case problems.

I'd also recommend an `if-else-statement`, not a second `if-statement`. Your code would look like this:

```
mood=mood.toLowerCase()

if (mood.equals("happy")) {
    System.out.println("test");
}

else if (mood.equals("sad")) {
    System.out.println("I am sad");

}
```

These are all pretty basic java concepts, so I'd recommend reading more thoroughly about some of them. You can check out some of the documentation and/or other questions here:

- [if-else statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)
- [Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)
- [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I really appreciate it. If you wouldn't mind telling me one more thing; How do I set the output to anything else. Say the user inputs text that's not recognized by the program, how would I output something like "Mood not Understood" or something?

Comment: You could a final `else` statement that would print your message. If `mood` went through every condition without matching any of them, then your program would print the message at the end. Also glad I could help.

Comment: @Hasteify a Switch would be better if that's the case

Comment: @AsshO.Le I agree, but since he was already implementing an if-else ladder, I kept with the theme. He didn't want to completely rewrite, he just wanted to solve his problem.

Comment: @Wold yes you are correct :) im just adding some thing that would help him in the future :)

Comment: @AsshO.Le No harm in that!

Answer (score 3):

Cant compare strings like this

```
if (sc = happy)  // also, you never declare a happy variable. So use the 
                 // stirng literal like I did below
// also can't compare to Scanner instance
// instead compare to mood
```

Use equals

```
if ("happy".equals(mood)) {  // Caught commenter, can't use sc to compare, use mood
    // do something
}
```

Also, if in the future, you needed to use an = operation for comparison (for anything but strings), you would use a double ==

Comment: `sc` is an instance of `Scanner`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't catch that.

Answer (score 1):

Always make use of .equals(..) method to compare String values..

```
if (mood.equals("happy")) 
  System.out.println("test");

if (mood.equals("sad")) 
    System.out.println("I am sad");
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be like this

```
    if ("happy".equals(mood)
{
    System.out.println("IM HAPPYYYYYYY!!!!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How I think you can approach this problem is by specify a set of pre-defined input parameter for the user to choose from then respond accordingly based on there choice e.g:

```
 System.out.println ("Enter you mood: [1 = happy,2 = sad,3 = confused]");
 int input = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt ();

 switch (input)
 {
   case 1:  System.out.println ("I am happy");break;
   case 2:  System.out.println ("I am sad");break;
   default: System.out.println ("I don't recognize your mood");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct the following things:

1. single **=** means indicates assignment, not comparison.
2. I assume you would like to check whether the string entered is equal to "happy" and "sad". Use **equals** method rather than "==" for checking string values.
3. why you put if (sc = sad) inside if (sc = happy). the inside check will never executed.
4. You need to check the values entered from console, rather than using Scanner sc itself.

So I think you need to change the code like follows:

String mood = sc.nextLine();

```
    if (mood.equals("happy")) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    if (mood.equals("sad")) {
        System.out.println("I am sad");
    }
```